# Product polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_7$

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to compute the product polynomial $$(x^3+3x^2+3x+1)(x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)$$

when the coefficients are regarded as elements of the field $\mathbb{F}_7$.

I just want someone to explain to me what does it mean when a cofficient (let us take 3 for example) is in $\mathbb{F}_7$ ? I know that $\mathbb{F}_7= \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: It means that when you compute e.g. $3\cdot 4$, you reduce the result modulo $7$, so you get $12 - 7 = 5$. Of course there's a short-cut here.

Comment: And by "short-cut" @DanielFischer is referring to (HINT) the factorization of the polynomials you are multiplying together.  Find out what the factors are, and you will certainly have a much easier time multiplying them together.

Comment: @DanielFischer What happens in the cases 1 and 21 ?

Comment: Well, modulo $7$, we have $21 = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer and 1 ? because I have a term $x^7$

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol Whenever you get a number greater than $6$ in your computations, just subtract $7$s from it until you get a number between $0$ and $6$. Equivalently, you can find the remainder of the number when divided by $7$.

Comment: Well, $1 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. So $1$ remains $1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Therefore the result is $x^7+1$ modulo 7

Comment: Yup. $(x+1)^3(x+1)^4 = (x+1)^7 \equiv x^7 + 1^7 \pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: Use Binomial Theorem to factor the two polynomials. What do you know about $(a+b)^p$ when $a,b\in\Bbb F_p$? If the answer to that question is "I'm not sure," don't worry: you can just use Binomial Theorem again to expand the product, and remember that integer multiples of $7$ are equal to $0$ *modulo* $7$.

Comment: But what do we know about $(a+b)^p$ when $a,b\in\Bbb F_p$ really?

Comment: @C_Arietta_C, are you asking for clarification of some kind?

Comment: Oh I guess it's been clarified in subsequent exercises, but for confirmation, did you mean Fermat’s little Theorem ($a^p \equiv a\; \rm{mod}\; p$) there?

Comment: Not the theorem per se, but its proof by induction is roughly along the same line.

Comment: @C_Arietta_C, I can't swear to this (almost exactly a decade after posting this answer), but I suspect I was thinking of the [Freshman's Dream Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream), instead. I often forget about Fermat's Little Theorem, but it occurs to me that the FDT makes it almost trivial to prove the Little Theorem by induction.

Comment: @C_Arietta_C, I suspect FDT further because $x$ is an indeterminate, rather than an element of the field $\mathbb{F}_7,$ so FlT doesn't apply.

Comment: But why doesn't the latter apply in that case? The equivalence holds for arbitrary integer $a$, and $x$ has to be an integer anyway, to wit, if FDT is to be applied.

Comment: @C_Arietta_C, actually, FDT applies even when $x$ is an indeterminate, since $0x=0$ by definition. Of course, any integer substituted for $x$ *will* have FlT apply, so instead of $x^7+1$ for indeterminate $x,$ we will get $x+1$ whenever we know $x$ to be an integer.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment! I finally got FDT’s point, though still feeling quite abstract as to how such a polynomial might look like, with coefficients in a prime field while indeterminates ‘indeterminate’…

Comment: @C_Arietta_C, the word "abstract" is well-chosen. Consider the set of all sequences of elements of $\mathbb{F}_7$ such that each sequence is eventually $0$--that is, each sequence has only finitely-many (if any) non-$0$ terms. We can define operations of addition and multiplication on this set of sequences such that for all intents and purposes, this set of sequences *is* the set of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_7$ and a single indeterminate. This abstract fact may or may not be *useful*, depending on why we're thinking about these sequences, but it is a fact, nonetheless.

Comment: Well, what I find «abstract» is rather that we seem to be stretching the operation in a prime field illegally, if addition in $\mathbb{F}_p$ cannot be extended to, say $\mathbb{N}$, then how are we to interpret the addition sign in $x^p+1$, and $(x+1)^p$ in the first place? In other words, if $x$ is not necessarily in  $\mathbb{F}_p$ but the coefficients are, where shall $x+1$ belong? Or is the $1$ in $x+1$ somehow different, and the latter is really a special case of $x+y$, so only in expansion of the binomial $(x+y)^p$ are we going to encounter the said coefficients?

Comment: But what does that mean? Am I missing anything?

Comment: @C_Arietta_C, the "short" version is that we are extending addition from $\mathbb{F}_p$ to $\mathbb{F}_p[x],$ an infinite-dimensional, commutative, unital algebra over the prime field $\mathbb{F}_p.$ Everything you mentioned, including the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p,$ can be thought of as living inside the much larger structure of $\mathbb{F}_p[x],$ except for $(x+y)^p.$ That lives in the "larger" algebra $\mathbb{F}_p[x,y].$

Comment: I know that isn't very enlightening on its own. The best advice I can give, though, is to remember that function is more important than form, here, which is why isomorphisms are so incredibly useful. For instance, the set of positive real numbers $x$ with the multiplication operation isn't nearly as easy to understand as the set of real numbers $y$ with the addition operation. However, they are functionally the same, as groups, since the maps $x\mapsto\ln(x)$ and $y\mapsto e^y$ can be shown to be isomorphisms between them!

Answer (score 3):

We use $3$ as shorthand for the coset $$7\mathbb{Z}+3=\{\ldots,-11,-4,3,10,17,\ldots\}$$ in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $$\cdots=7\mathbb{Z}-11=7\mathbb{Z}-4=7\mathbb{Z}+3=3\mathbb{Z}+10=3\mathbb{Z}+17=\cdots,$$ when working in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, we have $$\cdots=-11=-4=3=10=17=\cdots.$$

Practically, this means if $k$ arises as a coefficient, we can replace $k$ with $k \text{ mod } 7$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can multiply two polynomials in the usual way first, then you look at the coefficients and reduce them to modulo 7. For example:
$(3x^2+x+1)(x^2+3x+6) = 3x^2(x^2+3x+6)+x(x^2+3x+6)+1.(x^2+3x+6)=(3x^4+9x^3+18x^2)+(x^3+3x^2+6x)+(x^2+3x+6)=3x^4+10x^3+22x^2+9x+6$ which is the same as $3x^4+3x^3+x^2+2x-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ because $10 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$, $22 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, $9 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ and $6 \equiv -1 \pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, an integer $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p\equiv{n\mod p}$.  So coefficients can only be in the set $\{0,1,2,...,p-2, p-1\}$ Thus, you can knock out terms with coefficients of the form $pn$.  In your case multiples of $7\equiv{0\mod7}$.

I will add a little more of a hint to cameron's

$(a+b)^p={p\choose0}a^p+{p\choose 1}a^{p-1}b+{p\choose 2}a^{p-2}b^2+...+{p\choose p-1}ab^{p-1}+{p\choose p}b^p$

$=\frac{p!}{p!0!}a^p+\frac{p!}{(p-1)!1!}a^{p-1}b+\frac{p!}{(p-2)!2!}a^{p-2}b^2+...+\frac{p!}{1!(p-1)!}ab^{p-1}+\frac{p!}{0!p!}b^p$

$=1a^p+pa^{p-1}b+\frac{p(p-1)}{2}a^{p-2}b^2+...+pab^{p-1}+1b^p$

$=a^p+0a^{p-1}b+0a^{p-2}b^2+...+0ab^{p-1}+b^p$

$=a^p+b^p$

Comment: you didn't answer his question, you just explained that $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: you're right.  I'll amend